# Performance of comparisons in C++ ( foo >= 0 vs. foo != 0 )

Tags: c++, performance

I've been working on a piece of code recently where performance is very important, and essentially I have the following situation:

```
int len = some_very_big_number;
int counter = some_rather_small_number;

for( int i = len; i >= 0; --i ){
    while( counter > 0 && costly other stuff here ){
        /* do stuff */
        --counter;
    }
    /* do more stuff */
}
```

So here I have a loop that runs very often and for a certain number of runs the while block will be executed as well until the variable `counter` is reduced to zero and then the while loop will not be called because the first expression will be false.

The question is now, if there is a difference in performance between using
`counter > 0` and `counter != 0`?
I suspect there would be, does anyone know specifics about this.

Comment: I feel like the 2nd while loop ought to be a for loop.  This change will have no impact on performance.

Comment: Even if there was a difference, it might be... say 1 clock cycle? Is this really going to change your result...

Comment: Well technically yes. :)

Comment: You haven't said which platform you're on, which compiler you use, and which settings of the compiler. How we're supposed to measure it for you if we don't even know _what_ to measure? -1 You might have to do it yourself.

Comment: Suppose, just for argument's sake, it did make a difference. How big could that difference possibly be compared to your `costly other stuff here`.

Comment: BTW, I would code that outer loop as `for (int i = len; --i >= 0; )`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you think that what will solve your problem! :D

```
    if(x >= 0)
00CA1011  cmp         dword ptr [esp],0 
00CA1015  jl          main+2Ch (0CA102Ch) <----
...
    if(x != 0)
00CA1026  cmp         dword ptr [esp],0 
00CA102A  je          main+3Bh (0CA103Bh) <----
```

Comment: The output I got was jg and jne instead of jl and je, but they're a wash.  Times to execute these instructions are the same.

Comment: @KFro What compiler are you using? I am using VC2008 (default release mode)

Comment: Just to expand a bit on this, in x86 both `je` and `jl` jump based on the flags.  However, the flags are generated by the `cmp` in both cases, so *calculation* has the same performance either way.  The *decision* while based on different flags, will also have the same latency, since the flags are already available, and checking the flags is done in parallel for all flags at once anyway.

Comment: ...and then you might start to wonder which one your CPU's branch predictor gets right more often.

Answer (score 33):

To measure is to know.

Comment: I'd like to disagree, but I'd have to go find a better one first.

Comment: I would have written that, "tias".

Comment: Demn is this an unswer? There was a question! Zebrabox do you measyre or could you measure everything to know the quantity?

Comment: @SadSido: You're right with that. IIRC, it goes like this: To know is to err. `:)`

Answer (score 18):

In programming, the following statement is the sign designating the road to Hell:

> I've been working on a piece of code recently where performance is very important

Write your code in the cleanest, most easy to understand way. Period.

Once that is done, you can measure its runtime. If it takes too long, *measure* the bottlenecks, and speed up the biggest ones. Keep doing that until it is fast enough.

The list of projects that failed or suffered catastrophic loss due to a misguided emphasis on blind optimization is large and tragic. Don't join them.

Comment: Your advice might apply generally but in this case, either way of writing this makes no difference for clarity and readability. Furthermore, the code *is* very sensitive to performance (I happen to know it …), in fact the whole goal of this project is to squeeze every last ounce of performance from the CPU (and that includes micro-optimizations in tight loops).

Comment: I note that, while you assure that this loop is performance-critical, you haven't written that you found this out through measuring. So how do you know?

Comment: If you know fine, but you still have to measure. It could be that you are wasting time trying to figure out how to save 60 CPU cycles in a loop that has 60,000 of them to save somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're spending time optimizing the wrong thing. "costly other stuff here", "do stuff" and "do more stuff" are more important to look at. That is where you'll make the big performance improvements I bet.

Answer (score 4):

There will be a *huge* difference if the counter starts with a negative number. Otherwise, on every platform I'm familiar with, there won't be a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a difference between `counter > 0` and `counter != 0`? It depends on the platform.

A very common type of CPU are those from Intel we have in our PC's. Both comparisons will map to a single instruction on that CPU and I assume they will execute at the same speed. However, to be certain you will have to perform your own benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim said, when in doubt see for yourself :

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    ptime Before = microsec_clock::universal_time(); // UTC NOW
    // do stuff here
    ptime After = microsec_clock::universal_time(); // UTC NOW
    time_duration delta_t = After - Before; // How much time has passed?
    cout << delta_t.total_seconds() << endl; // how much seconds total?
    cout << delta_t.fractional_seconds() << endl; // how much microseconds total?
}
```

Here's a pretty nifty way of measuring time. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is that his "do stuff" is a boolean comparison. Most likely the two calls to universal_time() take far longer than the thing being measured. Even if you changed the calls to RTDSC instructions, that plus the math probably takes longer. Any measurement done this way is liable to be awash in noise.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you can measure this, sure.  However, these sorts of comparisons are so fast that you are probably going to see more variation based on processor swapping and scheduling then on this single line of code.

This smells of unnecessary, and premature, optimization.  Right your program, optimize what you see.  If you need more, profile, and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that the overwhelming performance aspects of this code on modern cpus will be dominated not by the comparison *instruction* but whether the comparison is *well predicted* since any mis-predict will waste many more cycles than any integral operation.

As such loop unrolling will probably be the biggest winner but measure, measure, measure.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that the type of comparison is going to make a difference, without knowing it, is the definition of **guessing**.

Don't guess.

Answer (score 0):

In general, they should be equivalent (both are usually implemented in single-cycle instructions/micro-ops).  Your compiler may do some strange special-case optimization that is difficult to reason about from the source level, which may make either one slightly faster.  Also, equality testing is more energy-efficient than inequality testing (>), though the system-level effect is so small as to not merit discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no difference.  You could try examining the assembly output for each.

That being said, the only way to tell if any difference is significant is to try it both ways and measure.  I'd bet that the change makes no difference whatsoever with optimizations on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing for the x86 architecture, when you look at the assembly output it will come down to jns vs jne. jns will check the sign flag and jne will check the zero flag. Both operations, should as far as I know, be equally costly.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the solution is to use the correct data type.

Make counter an unsigned int.  Then it can't be less than zero.  Your compiler will obviously know this and be forced to choose the optimal solution.

Or you could just measure it.

You could also think about how it would be implemented...(here we go on a tangent)...

- less than zero: the sign bit would be set, so need to check 1 bit
- equal to zero : the whole value would be zero, so need to check all the bits

Of course, computers are funny things, and it may take longer to check a single bit than the whole value (however many bytes it is on your platform).

You could just measure it...

And you could find out that one it more optimal than another (under the conditions you measured it).  But your program will still run like a dog because you spent all your time optimising the wrong part of your code.

The best solution is to use what many large software companies do - blame the hardware for not runnnig fast enough and encourage your customer to upgrade their equipment (which is clearly inferior since your product doesn't run fast enough).

< /rant>

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question just now, 3 years after it is asked, so I am not sure how useful the answer will still be... Still, I am surprised not to see clearly stated that answering your question requires to know two and only two things:

1. which processor you target
2. which compiler you work with

To the first point, each processor has different instructions for tests.  On one given processor, two similar comparisons may turn up to take a different number of cycles.  For example, you may have a 1-cycle instruction to do a gt (>), eq (==), or a le (<=), but no 1-cycle instruction for other comparisons like a ge (>=).  Following a test, you may decide to execute conditional instructions, or, more often, as in your code example, take a jump.  There again, cycles spent in jumps take a variable number of cycles on most high-end processors, depending whether the conditional jump is taken or not taken, predicted or not predicted.  When you write code in assembly and your code is time critical, you can actually take quite a bit of time to figure out how to best arrange your code to minimize overall the cycle count and may end up in a solution that may have to be optimized based on the number of time a given comparison returns a true or false.

Which leads me to the second point: compilers, like human coders, try to arrange the code to take into account the instructions available and their latencies.  Their job is harder because some assumptions an assembly code would know like "counter is small" is hard (not impossible) to know.  For trivial cases like a loop counter, most modern compilers can at least recognize the counter will always be positive and that a != will be the same as a > and thus generate the best code accordingly.  But that, as many mentioned in the posts, you will only know if you either run measurements, or inspect your assembly code and convince yourself this is the best you could do in assembly.  And when you upgrade to a new compiler, you may then get a different answer.