# In swift which loop is faster `for` or `for-in`? Why?

Tags: swift

Which loop should I use when have to be extremely aware of the time it takes to iterate over a large array.

Comment: Did you try and measure it?

Comment: just like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364603/performance-of-comparisons-in-c-foo-0-vs-foo-0/1364614#1364614

Comment: @MartinR no not really. If you know please write the answer. I will definitely try measuring it.

Comment: Is it that easy that I have been awarded -1

Comment: I did not down vote, but actually it IS that easy. Let your loops run a million times for both cases. In that case you can use your wrist watch to measure the difference. And if there's not difference then: what the heck?

Answer (score 17):

#### Short answer

Don’t micro-optimize like this – any difference there is could be far outweighed by the speed of the operation you are performing inside the loop.  If you truly think this loop is a performance bottleneck, perhaps you would be better served by using something like the [accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) – but only if profiling shows you that effort is truly worth it.

And don’t fight the language. Use `for…in` unless what you want to achieve cannot be expressed with `for…in`.  These cases are rare.  The benefit of `for…in` is that it’s incredibly hard to get it wrong.  That is much more important.  Prioritize correctness over speed.  Clarity is important.  You might even want to skip a for loop entirely and use `map` or `reduce`.

#### Longer Answer

For arrays, if you try them without the fastest compiler optimization, they perform identically, because they essentially do the same thing.

Presumably your `for ;;` loop looks something like this:

```
var sum = 0
for var i = 0; i < a.count; ++i {
    sum += a[i]
}
```

and your `for…in` loop something like this:

```
for x in a {
    sum += x
}
```

Let’s rewrite the `for…in` to show what is really going on under the covers:

```
var g = a.generate()
while let x = g.next() {
    sum += x
}
```

And then let’s rewrite that for what `a.generate()` returns, and something like what the `let` is doing:

```
 var g = IndexingGenerator<[Int]>(a)
 var wrapped_x = g.next()
 while wrapped_x != nil {
     let x = wrapped_x!
     sum += x
     wrapped_x = g.next()
 }
```

Here is what the implementation for `IndexingGenerator<[Int]>` might look like:

```
struct IndexingGeneratorArrayOfInt {
    private let _seq: [Int]
    var _idx: Int = 0

    init(_ seq: [Int]) {
        _seq = seq
    }

    mutating func generate() -> Int? {
        if _idx != _seq.endIndex {
            return _seq[_idx++]
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Wow, that’s a lot of code, surely it performs way slower than the regular `for ;;` loop!

Nope.  Because while that might be what it is logically doing, the compiler has a lot of latitude to optimize.  For example, note that `IndexingGeneratorArrayOfInt` is a `struct` not a `class`.  This means it has no overhead over declaring the two member variables directly.  It also means the compiler might be able to inline the code in `generate` – there is no indirection going on here, no overloaded methods and vtables or objc_MsgSend.  Just some simple pointer arithmetic and deferencing.  If you strip away all the syntax for the structs and method calls, you’ll find that what the `for…in` code ends up being is almost exactly the same as what the `for ;;` loop is doing.

#### `for…in` helps avoid performance errors

If, on the other hand, for the code given at the beginning, you switch compiler optimization to the faster setting, `for…in` appears to blow `for ;;` away.  In some non-scientific tests I ran using `XCTestCase.measureBlock`, summing a large array of random numbers, it was an order of magnitude faster.

Why?  Because of the use of `count`:

```
for var i = 0; i < a.count; ++i {
                // ^-- calling a.count every time...
    sum += a[i]
}
```

Maybe the optimizer could have fixed this for you, but in this case it hasn’t.  If you pull the invariant out, it goes back to being the same as `for…in` in terms of speed:

```
let count = a.count
for var i = 0; i < count; ++i {
    sum += a[i]
}
```

“Oh, I would definitely do that every time, so it doesn’t matter”.  To which I say, really?  Are you sure?  Bet you forget sometimes.

But you want the even better news?  Doing the same summation with `reduce` was (in my, again not very scientific, tests) even faster than the for loops:

```
let sum = a.reduce(0,+)
```

But it is also so much more expressive and readable (IMO), and allows you to use `let` to declare your result.  Given that this should be your primary goal anyway, the speed is an added bonus.  But hopefully the performance will give you an incentive to do it regardless.

This is just for arrays, but what about other collections?  Of course this depends on the implementation but there’s a good reason to believe it would be faster for other collections like dictionaries, custom user-defined collections.

My reason for this would be that the author of the collection can implement an optimized version of `generate`, because they know exactly how the collection is being used.  Suppose subscript lookup involves some calculation (such as pointer arithmetic in the case of an array - you have to add multiple the index by the value size then add that to the base pointer).  In the case of generate, you know what is being done is to sequentially walk the collection, and therefore you could optimize for this (for example, in the case of an array, hold a pointer to the next element which you increment each time `next` is called).  Same goes for specialized member versions of `reduce` or `map`.

This might even be why `reduce` is performing so well on arrays – who knows (you could stick a breakpoint on the function passed in if you wanted to try and find out).  But it’s just another justification for using the language construct you should probably be using regardless.

Answer (score 5):

Famously stated: "*We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil*" Donald Knuth.  It seems unlikely that you are in the %3.

Focus on the bigger problem at hand.  After it is working, if it needs a performance boost, then worry about `for` loops.  But I guarantee you, in the end, bigger structural inefficiencies or poor algorithm choice will be the performance problem, not a `for` loop.

Worrying about `for` loops is oh so 1960s.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, a rudimentary playground test shows map() is about 10 times faster than for enumeration:

```
class SomeClass1 {
  let value: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(100)
}
class SomeClass2 {
  let value: UInt32
  init(value: UInt32) {
    self.value = value
  }
}
var someClass1s = [SomeClass1]()
for _ in 0..<1000 {
  someClass1s.append(SomeClass1())
}

var someClass2s = [SomeClass2]()
let startTimeInterval1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
someClass1s.map { someClass2s.append(SomeClass2(value: $0.value)) }
println("Time1: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTimeInterval1)") // "Time1: 0.489435970783234"
var someMoreClass2s = [SomeClass2]()
let startTimeInterval2 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for item in someClass1s { someMoreClass2s.append(SomeClass2(value: item.value)) }
println("Time2: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTimeInterval2)") // "Time2 : 4.81457495689392"
```

Answer (score 0):

The for (with a counter) is just incrementing a counter. Very fast. The for-in uses an iterator (call object to pass the next element). This is much slower. But finally you want to access the element in both cases wich will then make no difference in the end.

Comment: “The for-in uses an iterator (call object to pass the next element). This is much slower.” – chances are the opposite is the case, see my answer.

Comment: My summary "no difference in the end." was the point I wanted to set. Basically I'd go with @GoZoner. For those reasons I did not spend much effort in my post. I mean: the loop does not count. It depends on what's `inside` the loop.